# I can't run my python code -> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I don't know why my code doesn't work, I Import the library in the first line

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

Knowing that I've already install flask_sqlalchemy
[image]

Comment: `pip freeze` to ensure it's installed.

Comment: @erip  I found these packages  `Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2 SQLAlchemy==1.2.6` and other packages does not related to alchemy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*If it is a flask app* you should run the app in virtualenv, otherwise simply running by `python appName.py` will give that error. 
The other way is "`set FLASK_APP=appName.py`" then run `flask run`.

Comment: I'd argue that one should _always_ run a virtualenv -- not just for Flask apps.

Comment: Yes I agree... Cause virtualenv allows us to have isolated environment, which is helpful when we have two applications both require different versions of library sets. (without virtualenv we'd end up upgrading the library which the other apps don't support or require earlier versions)

Answer (score -1):

The first thing I'd check would be can you import the whole flask_sqlalchemy module:

`import flask_sqlalchemy`

If that works, it could be a case or spelling issue as that command works in my local environment.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you installed the wrong package. If you are using python3 you have to use `python3 -m pip install <module>`